# Get User Info after Login in Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After login I want to get the user information of the logged in user.

I have no idea how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
public class Dashboard extends Fragment {

    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chamas").child("Users");

        mFirebaseUser.getName();
            // User ID
        mFirebaseUser.getUid();
            // Email-ID
        mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
            // User-Profile (if available)
        mFirebaseUser.getPhone();

        return view;
    }
```

This is not working at all, can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use auth state before the app has even initialized, by putting it into the class definition. This is invoked long before the asynchronous call to verify auth credentials has completed.

As explained in the guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users), "getCurrentUser might also return null because the auth object has not finished initializing."

It's a little hard to tell what you actually need here, since you haven't included any info about the auth workflow. You may want to fetch the user data in onStart() as shown in the examples:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}
```

Another approach is to store the user data after auth completes:

```
private FirebaseUser user;

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, store user data
                        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    } else {
                        // Sign in fails...
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

Another approach is to monitor auth state:

```
FirebaseUser user;

@Override
private void onCreate() {
   firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
         if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
         }
      }
  };
}
```